# HTML import with pre-defined Word styles

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-word-2010, html, css, styles

I'm having a web application which is generating simple text output with basic html tags like `h1`, `h2`, `ul`, `em` and `a`. I am *not* styling them with any attributes or CSS. Then I select the whole output in Internet Explorer, go to Microsoft Word (tested on 2007 and 2010) and paste it with *Keep Source Formatting*.

The pasted text looks *a little bit* like formated. I can see which are the headers. But it does not apply the default Word styles like *Heading 1* for `h1`. in fact it applies the paragraph formatting *Normal* to all of them but styles them individually (e.g. font, alignment, spacing) according to *style inspector*.

Is there a possibility in which I may pre-link HTML/CSS styles with the Word styles? Something like `<h1 class="Heading 1">` which would be recognized and adopted by Word during paste.